# How to route to a url based on data entered in Django form?

Tags: python, django

At first , I would like to take an integer input from user . After getting the input , I would like to go to the url based on what the user has entered . However , I am not able to implement it . 
Here's my urls.py file:

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.page1),
    re_path(r'^form/(?P<data>[1-4]{1})',views.page2),
]
```

Here's my views.py file:

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import CustomForm1
from django.http import HttpResponse
import requests
# Create your views here.
def page1(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CutsomForm1(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            data = form.cleaned_data['data']
    else:
        form = CustomForm1
        data = 0
    return render(request,'homepage/base.html',{'form':form,'data':data})
```

This is my forms.py file:

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms

class CustomForm1(forms.Form):
    data = forms.IntegerField(label='data',required=True)
```

And here's the HTMl:

**HTML**

```
<form method="POST" action="form/{{ data }}">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <ul class="actions">
                <li><input type="submit" value="Send Message" class="primary" /></li>
                <li><input type="reset" value="Clear" /></li>
            </ul>
        </form>
```

Initially , when the form is loaded , my `data` variable has value 0 , but I want to it get the value which is entered by user , hence , I can then route to the desired url as per the updated `data` variable which is passed as context .

For example , in the input field ,if the user enters `1` , I want it to go to `form/1` but i feel that the django templating is static and is not updateable once passed.Any other way I can implement it?

Comment: `django` is a server-side framework. It doesn't work on the client-side(browser). You may use `javascript` to capture the user input and redirect it accordingly.

Comment: Oh! Will try it out using JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

In views.py :

```py
from django.urls import reverse
from django.urls import redirect

def page1(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomForm1(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            data = form.cleaned_data['data']
            return redirect(reverse('form_url', kwargs = {'data' : data}))
    else:
        form = CustomForm1
        data = 0
    return render(request,'homepage/base.html',{'form':form,'data':data})
```

urls.py:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.page1),
    re_path(r'^form/(?P<data>[1-4]{1})',views.page2, name = 'form_url')
]
```

Basically I cleaned `1` from the form and used `reverse` to create the url and I redirected to it.
Read about reverse : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse

**[EDIT]** as @mihai mentioned in the comments, remove the `action="form/{{ data }}"` if you want this answer to work.

Comment: The call to `redirect` [can be simplified](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#examples) as in the docs: `redirect('form_url', data=data)`.

Comment: I tried `reverse` out but it is still redirecting me to `form/0` . Also , tried out `redirect`as the above comment states but I am still not able to do it. `redirect` loads the same page but this time with different data right?

Comment: You need to also remove the `action="/form/{{ data }}/"` in your template if you want to use this answer. You should probably clarify in your question what you are trying to achieve. From what I gather, page1 has a form where you select a number from 1 to 4, and when you submit the form, you go to the page2 view (which btw you haven't included in your question) corresponding to that number. If so, then omit the `action` attribute of the form to send data to the same page1 view where the form is initially rendered, since that's where the code handling the POST is located.

Comment: Yes. I want to first take an input from the first form (any number from 1 to 4) and then after filling the form , I want to route the url to `form/1` or `form/2` likewise depending upon the input entered . Also tried out what you suggested and it worked! Thank you very much!